# How to add line breaks between inline-block elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have list of images. I want to put a **line break** after the second image using CSS. I have used a CSS trick listed below but it doesn't work for the inline-block elements. It only works for display inline elements

Code that working for inline Elements.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a:nth-of-type(2):after
{
    white-space: pre;content:'\A';
}
img:nth-of-type(2):after
{
    white-space: pre;content:'\A';
}
```

If I am using img element which is display:inine-block by default. The above CSS does not working for it.

Check below fiddle for example

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/dD52z/1/

Please let me know if there any way of doing it

**Note** - I cannot change the HTML structure as it is coming through database.

Comment: Get anywhere on this issue?  I'm looking for exactly the same thing, except I'd like to see this with `<a/>`s and `<li/>`s.

Comment: @Mike.. I searched a lot but that i didn't got any solution.. if you got any then please post answer here..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use :after pseudo elements with `<img>` tag. This is because pseudo elements work only with double tags. For achieving the desired result you can give `<br>` tag after each `<img>` and style the `<br>` instead.

```
<div>
  <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
  <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
  <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
  <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
  <br>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
  <br>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
  <br>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
  <br>
</div>
```

And in the css you can style the `<br>` tag like this:

```
a:nth-of-type(2):after
{
    white-space: pre;content:'\A';
}
br{
  display: none;
}
br:nth-of-type(2){
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use :after pseudo elements with <img> tag. This is because pseudo elements work only with double tags..

Do you have any documentation for this statement ? or any reference link ?

Comment: One more I cannot change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

```
img:nth-of-type(2n)
{
  float: left;
}

img:nth-of-type(2n-1)
{
    display: inline;
    clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

Inline as default, float left and nothing (clear) on left. But on FIRST (and even) not the SECOND.

To put image centered in the div, just add also a padding.

2nd edit:

```
      <div>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
    <a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
  </div>
<div id="outer" style="background: yellow;  margin:0px auto; width: 110px">
  <div id="fromsql">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" />
  </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

So basically you can add an outer div with a fixed size and center it. Elements inside div fromsql keep floating in a reduced space

Comment: Check if you can add an outer div like i had. Edited 2nd time. http://jsfiddle.net/YL6Lp/

Comment: Really thanks. But It is inside a slider. Means outer div width is 100%.. So cannot give fixed width to it..

Comment: Well, i think that you need to add line break with a javascript. If you can't use float a js that trigger after db query can solve your issue.

Comment: Yes. I have to do it using JS only. In CSS there is no possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can break line after each inline block.

```
div { letter-spacing: 9999px; }

div a, div img { display: inline-block; letter-spacing: initial; }
```

Comment: I want to put a line break after the second image using CSS. Your answer will put line break after every element.

Answer (score -1):

```
a:nth-of-type(2), img:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answre. But it is adding line break before and after the second image... I want the line break only after the second image..

Answer (score -1):

Try div>img>img as selector. Add some bottom margin.

Hope this is what youre looking for?

Another way is to wrap the two images in a div

Answer (score -1):

It will work if you'll make it block

```
img:nth-of-type(2)
{
    display:block;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is adding line break before and after the second image... I want the line break only after the second image.

Comment: As I read in your comments you want to create responsive site, but why you can not use JS it's would not prevents to make it responsive, one more question, can you make your div width fixed?

Comment: If I have 3 breakpoints desktop, tabletes and mobile. I want the line break after 4 element in desktop... after 3 element in tab... and after 2nd element for the mobile.. So Use of JS will be more complicated.. JS is last option to use.. I am trying to find solutions using CSS>

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the effect you're trying to achieve, an alternative - and potentially simpler - way to achieve the same effect might be to use floated block (as opposed to inline-block) elements, which would allow you to use `clear: left` to produce a line-break wherever required.

Comment: If I am using floated elemesnts. I am unable to make the imgs in the center of outer div.